# How do you kill the man eating plants?

Tags: android, mines-of-mars

In several of the dungeons there are giant man eating plants that snap at you if you get too close, the first one I came across I killed easily with the shotgun, but now nothing seems to kill them. Is there some special trick to it that I missed, or have I accidentally skipped a dungeon and the game is preventing me from continuing?

Comment: Game is "Mines of Mars" but it won't let me tag for some reason

Comment: Tag added for you.